# É seguro usar TimThumb?

Tags: php, wordpress, segurança, biblioteca, requisição

Estou fazendo um site e comecei a fazer o uso da biblioteca **TimThumb.php** para redimensionar as imagens no tamanho exato que eu quero. No entanto me veio duas dúvidas

1. Será que é seguro usar? ouvir dizer que versões passadas
   apresentaram    vulnerabilidade;
2. Fazendo o uso irá implicar em algo na performance do meu site? ex:
   mais trabalho para o servidor.

Comment: Não sei o status do timthumb hoje em dia, mas pra evitar dor de cabeça melhor usar funções nativas ([How to Dynamically Resize WordPress Image On-The-Fly (custom field/theme option)](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58323/12615)), confere o comentário do bueltge ali nessa resposta, o cara é um craque e soltou um plugin recente

Comment: +1 É uma boa preocupação. Sinceramente, eu vi o código-fonte do `Timthumb` e eu fiquei meio sismado. Tem um sistema aqui que usa o `Timthumb` (não foi eu que implementei), mas acho que seria uma boa ideia procurar um recurso mais atualizado do que ele.

Comment: https://www.ssl.net.br/blog/qual-plataforma-cms-mais-hackeada/ esse artigo clarifica que o uso do Timthumb está sim associado à vulnerabilidade do sistema, os próprios desenvolvedores, como disse o amigo na resposta anterior, já proclamaram o fato. Recomendo não usar.

Answer (score 2):

O Timthumb tem sim vulnerabilidades de segurança, os próprios desenvolvedores mencionaram isso uma vez (penso que foi no próprio blog/site deles) e vincularam que essa foi a razão pelo qual eles deixaram de continuar o seu desenvolvimento. Eu fiz uma breve pesquisa a ver se encontrava esse artigo mas não encontrei. Entretanto nunca mais segui as suas atualizações de status e de desenvolvimento, então não sei como se encontra a situação no momento e se eles já resolveram estas vulnerabilidades ou não, mas talvez possa haver outros desenvolvedores que possam ter pegado no projeto e tenham fixado este problema.

No entanto existem outros métodos e alternativas para este plugin.
[Pesquisando no Google](https://www.google.com/#q=timthumb+alternative) podemos encontrar algumas delas:

- Pergunta feita no SOen - [What's a good PHP alternative to Timthumb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28962157/3624981)
- Plugin [bfi_thumb](https://github.com/bfintal/bfi_thumb) para o WordPress que agora mudou e está a ser continuado como - **[OTF Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/otf-regenerate-thumbnails/)** ou no GitHub - https://github.com/gambitph/WP-OTF-Regenerate-Thumbnails

> Artigo em inglês falando de ambos, o [TimThumb e do BFIThumb](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/moving-away-from-timthumb-to-bfithumb--wp-33743)

- [Entre outros...](https://www.google.com/#q=timthumb+alternative)